# How do I import and export a wallet keypair generated from CLI to a wallet provider like phantom or solflare?

Tags: wallet, cli, keypair

How to Import and Export Wallets between CLI and Wallet providers?

How do I export my wallet keypair generated from the Solana CLI and import it into a wallet like phantom or solflare?

And how to export that wallet keypair from the wallet provider and import it back to a JSON file for the CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the the .json file created by the CLI and copy the contents(it should look like [12,54,11,64,etc...]). Then go to the wallet you want to use, select import private key and paste the contents.

Phantom: + Add/Connect Wallet > Import Private Key

Solflare: Settings > Account > Import A New Wallet > More Options > Import Private Key

Comment: hi thanks! does the reverse work for exporting from the wallet back to .json for CLI or how does that work?

Comment: you should ask this in a new post